# Q: Techniques for logging Apache requests to MySQL (on CentOS 7)

Tags: mysql, logging, apache2

I'm interested in logging my Apache logs to MySQL (for easier analysis, basically... and, to prevent the DB from getting huge, I was considering regularly purging requests older than XX months)

Googling mostly suggests using `mod_log_sql_mysql`, but this package doesn't seem to be available for CentOS 7. I came across an interesting page [here](https://escapequotes.net/save-apache-log-in-mysql-database/) where the author uses Apache's custom-log module to write to the `mysql` client through a pipe, but that seems pretty inefficient (spawning a mysql client for each log entry? Or is there a way to get Apache to do log updates as less-frequent batches?).

But that page gave me the idea of maybe writing a daemon to provide a unix socket or pipe that Apache could write to, and the daemon could maintain an open connection to the MySQL daemon *or* maybe just a daemon that uses inotify or fswatch to just watch for changes to the normal textual logs.

But, before I embark on one of these projects, does anybody have any thoughts about:

1. **Is there really no mod-log-ssl-mysql for CentOS 7?**
2. **If not, does one of these approaches (calling mysql for each entry, using a daemon to monitor a pipe, or using a daemon to monitor normal textual logs) seem to be the better route?**
3. **Is logging to a DB just a horrible idea, and I should forget that I ever had such a notion?**

I guess one of the advantages of writing my own daemon is that I could do clever things with the DB... instead of logging everything to a single table, I could give each requested file-path (since those tend to be long) an entry in a separate table and just reference it by its primary key in the request log.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I think it's fixed, now.

Comment: Yeah, that link seems to work. It's approximately what I was going to suggest...